# Powershell XMLDocument save as UTF-8 without BOM

Tags: .net, powershell, utf-8, byte-order-mark

I built an XML object of type System.Xml.XmlDocument.

```
$scheme.gettype()
IsPublic IsSerial Name BaseType                                                         
-------- -------- ---- --------                                                         
True     False    XmlDocument System.Xml.XmlNode
```

I use the method save() to save it to a file.

```
$scheme.save()
```

This saves the file in format UTF-8 with BOM. The BOM causes issues with other scripts down the line.

When we open the XML file in Notepad++ and save it as UTF-8 (without the BOM), other scripts down the line don't have a problem. So I've been asked to save the script without the BOM.

The [MS documentation for the save method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmldocument.save?view=netframework-4.8) states:

> The value of the encoding attribute is taken from the XmlDeclaration.Encoding property. If the XmlDocument does not have an XmlDeclaration, or if the XmlDeclaration does not have an encoding attribute, the saved document will not have one either.

The [MS documentation on XmlDeclaration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmldeclaration.encoding?view=netframework-4.8) lists encoding properties of UTF-8, UTF-16 and others. It does not mention a BOM.

Does the XmlDeclaration have an encoding property that leaves out the BOM?

PS. This behavior is identical in Powershell 5 and Powershell 7.

Comment: Which overload of `Save()` are you calling?  The latter half of the question deals with the `encoding` attribute of the `<?xml` declaration, yet the part about fixing the problem by resaving the file in Notepad++ suggests the real problem is the text encoding of the file itself.  For that you can create a UTF-8 non-BOM `StreamWriter` with `$encoding = New-Object -TypeName 'System.Text.UTF8Encoding' -ArgumentList $false; $writer = New-Object -TypeName 'System.IO.StreamWriter' -ArgumentList $outputPath, $shouldAppend, $encoding` and pass that to `Save()`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, the presence of an **explicit `encoding="utf-8"` attribute** in the declaration of an XML document causes .NET's `[xml]` (`System.Xml.XmlDocument`) type to [`.Save()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Xml.XmlDocument.Save) the document, when given a *file path*, to an **UTF-8-encoded file *with BOM***, which **can indeed cause problems** (even though it *shouldn't*<sup>[1]</sup>).

**[A request to change this](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/28218) has been *green-lighted in principle*, but is *not yet implemented as of .NET 6.0*** (due to a larger discussion about changing `[System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8` to *not* use a BOM, in which case `.Save()` would automatically not create a BOM anymore either).

Somewhat ironically, **the *absence* of an `encoding` attribute causes `.Save()` to create UTF-8-encoded files *without* a BOM**.

A simple solution is therefore to *remove* the encoding attribute<sup>[2]</sup>; e.g.:

```
# Create a sample XML document:
$xmlDoc = [xml] '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><foo>bar</foo>'

# Remove the 'encoding' attribute from the declaration.
# Without this, the .Save() method below would create a UTF-8 file *with* BOM.
$xmlDoc.ChildNodes[0].Encoding = $null

# Now, saving produces a UTf-8 file *without* a BOM.
$xmlDoc.Save("$PWD/out.xml")
```

---

<sup>[1] Per the [XML W3C Recommendation](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#charencoding): "entities encoded in UTF-8 MAY begin with the Byte Order Mark" [BOM].</sup>

<sup>[2] This is safe to do, because the [XML W3C Recommendation](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#charencoding) effectively mandates UTF-8 as the default in the absence of both a BOM and an `encoding` attribute.</sup>

Answer (score 5):

As [BACON explains in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63476408/powershell-xmldocument-save-as-utf-8-without-bom#comment112246254_63476408), the string value of the `Encoding` attribute in the XML declaration doesn't have any bearing on how the file containing the document is encoded.

You can control this by creating either a `StreamWriter` or an `XmlWriter` with a non-BOM `UTF8Encoding`, then pass *that* to `Save($writer)`:

```bsh
$filename = Resolve-Path path\to\output.xml

# Create UTF8Encoding instance, sans BOM
$encoding = [System.Text.UTF8Encoding]::new($false)

# Create StreamWriter instance
$writer = [System.IO.StreamWriter]::new($filename, $false, $encoding)

# Save using (either) writer
$scheme.Save($writer)

# Dispose of writer
$writer.Dispose()
```

Alternatively use an `[XmlWriter]`:

```
# XmlWriter Example
$writer = [System.Xml.XmlWriter]::Create($filename, @{ Encoding = $encoding })
```

The second argument is an [`[XmlWriterSettings]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlwritersettings) object, through which we can exercise greater control over formatting options in addition to explicitly set encoding:

```
$settings = [System.Xml.XmlWriterSettings]@{
  Encoding = $encoding
  Indent = $true
  NewLineOnAttributes = $true
}
$writer = [System.Xml.XmlWriter]::Create($filename, $settings)

#  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
#  <Config>
#    <Group
#      name="PropertyGroup">
#      <Property
#        id="1"
#        value="Foo" />
#      <Property
#        id="2"
#        value="Bar"
#        exclude="false" />
#    </Group>
#  </Config>
```